# How to pass extra arguments to Google Pagespeed API service object

Tags: python, api, google-api, pagespeed

I'm using the Google Pagespeed API v4 to extract Pagespeed scores for a large number of URLs. I want to test for both desktop and mobile with the argument `strategy` within my Pagespeed call. This is possible in the general API call, but I can't find a way to pass these arguments in the batch call.

Minimal working example:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import requests

#define Google API key and API call
google_api_key = "MyKey"
#build service object to call PageSpeed, version 4, with MyKey
ps_service = build('pagespeedonline', 'v4', developerKey = google_api_key)

list_of_urls = [a list of several URLs]

#define function; make list of URLs with column for PageSpeed score
def list_websites(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print("This is an exception: " + str(exception) + " " + request_id)
    else:
        score = response['ruleGroups']['SPEED']['score']
        print(score)

#create URL batch
ps_batch = ps_service.new_batch_http_request(callback = list_websites)
service_list = []

for url in list_of_urls:
    service_list.append(ps_service.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(url = url))

for req in service_list:
    ps_batch.add(req)

#execute API call by batch
ps_batch.execute()
```

Although this method works fine for doing batch requests to the API, by default it calculates a speed score based on a desktop view of the said URLs (the analysis strategy is set to desktop), whereas I would also like to receive a score for a batch request in which strategy is set to mobile, to get a score based on the mobile view of the URLs.

My question is, how do I add an extra argument to the build() function in which I can make a distinction between mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    service_list.append(ps_service.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(url = url, strategy='mobile'))
```

Every parameter, used by google can be sent that way